# Express $H$ as a product of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let  $\mathbb{Z}_n$ denote the additive cyclic group of order $n$. Let $G$ be the group $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_6 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{11}$ and let $H$ be the subgroup $\{6g \mid g \in G\}$.
>
> 1. Express the groups $H$ and $G/H$ as direct sums of cyclic groups.
> 2. Is $G$ isomorphic to $H \oplus G/H$?

So, given $(a,b,c)\in G$, $a$ can be $0,1,2,3$, $b$ can be $0,1,2,3,4,5$ and $c$ can be $0,1,...,10$. If $6(a,b,c)=(p,q,r)$ then $p$ can be $0,2$, $q$ can be $0$ and $r$ can be $0,1,...,10$. Hence, $H=\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{11}$. Then $G/H=\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$. I just wanted to make sure whether my answers and justifications are correct. Appreciate if point out any errors.

Comment: $H$ is correct but $G/H$ is wrong.

Comment: Here is the thing $G/H\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus \mathbb{Z}_6\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{11}}{\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_1\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{11}}\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}_4}{\mathbb{Z}_2}\oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}_6}{\mathbb{Z}_1}\oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}_{11}}{\mathbb{Z}_{11}}\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_6\oplus \mathbb{Z}_1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(0,0,z)\in G$; then, since $6\cdot2\equiv1\pmod{11}$, we have
$$
(0,0,z)=6(0,0,2z)
$$
Similarly,
$$
(2,0,z)=6(1,0,2z)
$$
so
$$
H=\{(x,0,z):x\in 2\mathbb{Z}_4,z\in\mathbb{Z}_{11}\}
$$
Now it's clear that $H\cong\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{11}$.

Also
$$
G/H\cong\mathbb{Z}_4/2\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus\mathbb{Z}_6
\cong\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{6}
\cong\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{3}
$$

Comment: Can you please explain why $\mathbb{Z}_4/2\mathbb{Z}_4=\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Let the homomorphism $\varphi: Z_4\to Z_2$ be defined by $\varphi(a)=2a$ then the kernal of that homomorphism is $2Z_4$. We have from this that $Z_4/2Z_4\cong Z_2$(Via homomorphism theorem)

Comment: @EpsilonDelta It's not “equal”, but “isomorphic”. It's a quotient of a cyclic group, hence cyclic, and has two elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your justification for $H$ is good, but I think you're wrong about $G/H$. Why did you choose that instead of $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_6$? The $q$ coordinate is fixed, and so the middle coordinate isn't restricted why you mod out by $H$.

$\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_6$ Contains multiple copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and they have different roles in the group structure. When you mod out, you need to make sure you're canceling the correct group. I the case of coordinate-determined subgroups, this is easy: you cancel the corresponding coordinate. So, modding out by your $H$, and modding out by $$H':=\{(p,q,r)|p=0,q\in\mathbb{Z}_2,r\in\mathbb{Z}_{11}\}$$ give different results, despite the fact that they are isomorphic, because they sit inside the larger group differently.

Comment: $G=\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_6\times \mathbb{Z}_{11}$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_6=\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_3$, I got $G/H=\frac{\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_{11}}{\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_{11}}=\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_3$. Is this wrong?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta compare $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ with $\mathbb Z_4$ - consider elements of order $4$

Comment: @EpsilonDelta the group you're modding out by doesn't effect the second coordinate and so doesn't break up the $\mathbb{Z}_6$. Order matters